# IndexError in Quiz program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having some problems creating a quiz for my son for his revision. It is a quiz which reads a text file, and displays questions in a random order. The quiz stops when he has answered every question twice.

So he can time himself, how would I add a timer in there which starts when the first question is displayed, and prints when he has answered every question correctly twice? I am using python 3.3.

Here is the code so far:

```
import random
import time
#open the text file
myfile = open("james.txt")
mylines = myfile.read().splitlines()
wrong = 0
#make blank lists
questions = []
answers = []
scores = []

#Seperate the file into Question and answer
for linenumber in range(0, len(mylines), 2):
        questions.append(mylines[linenumber])
        answers.append(mylines[linenumber+1])
        scores.append(0)

#Ask Question
for questionnumber in range(0,len(questions)):
        while scores[questionnumber] <2:
                questions.append(mylines[linenumber])
                questionnumber = random.randint(0,len(questions))
                print(questions[questionnumber])
                print(scores)
                #Generate Possible Answer
                possibleanswers = []
                possibleanswers.append(answers[questionnumber])
                for answerposition in range(1,3):
                        randomnum = random.randint(0,len(answers)-1)
                        while answers[randomnum] in possibleanswers:
                                randomnum = random.randint(0,len(answers)-1)
                        possibleanswers.append(answers[randomnum])
                #Shuffle  Answers
                random.shuffle(possibleanswers)
                for answernumber in range(0,len(possibleanswers)):
                        print(answernumber+1,possibleanswers[answernumber])

                input1 = int(input())
                givenanswer = possibleanswers[input1-1]
                if givenanswer == answers[questionnumber]:
                        print("Yes")
                        scores[questionnumber] = scores[questionnumber]+1
                else:
                        print("No, the answer was",questionnumber)
                        wrong = wrong+1
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback of the exception you are getting? The code you've posted is confusing enough that I don't know where to look.

Comment: it is totally random, sometimes it works to halfway, sometimes on the first question. It just says list index out of range

Comment: I understand that it may come up at random. But please post the traceback of the exception. It should start with `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and go on to describe exactly where in the code the exception happened.

Comment: Um, if you're seeing `list index out of range`, the rest of the traceback should be right above that. If it's not, can you give an example of the full output of your program (when it crashes)? It might also help if you could show an example data file. Edit those into the question.

Comment: Edited into the question

Answer (score 1):

```
questionnumber = random.randint(0,len(questions))
```

`randint` is inclusive, so it can return any number up to and including `len(questions)`. If it returns the largest possible number, then you'll get an IndexError. For instance, if `questions` is three elements long, then `questions[3]` will be out of range.

Reduce the allowable range of your random numbers:

```
questionnumber = random.randint(0,len(questions)-1)
```

---

Edit: there also appears to be a typo in your `#ask question` loop, that causes `questions` to grow larger than `answers`.

```
for questionnumber in range(0,len(questions)):
        while scores[questionnumber] <2:
                questions.append(mylines[linenumber])
              # ^^^ this line
```

This appears to be a copy-paste mistake. It doesn't make much sense to append to `questions` here, since it should already be fully populated after the `#Seperate` code. I suggest removing this line.

Comment: Or use `randrange`, which excludes its upper bound in the same way that `range` does.

Comment: I have used kevin's amendments, but it still comes up exactly the same?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the logic... Are your `questions` and `answers` lists always exactly the same size? If `questions` is ever longer than `answers`, then `answers[questionnumber]` can still go out of range even when `questions[questionnumber]` wouldn't.

Comment: yes there are 14 questions and answers( an answer to every question)

Comment: Yes, thank you ever so much, any ideas on how to get the timer in seconds?

Comment: [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time.time#time.time) should be useful there.